# jquery History on value change handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, history, handler

I'm using the History jquery plugin like that :

```
$.History.bind("anchor", function (state) {...});
```

And I wonder if there is a way to not specify the "anchor" but call a function when the anchor change no matter the anchor.
Because I'm using this anchor name to load content from a file whose name is the name of the anchor.

Something like this :

```
$.History.onValueChange(function(value){ ... getContent(value); });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it. Simply no need to precise which "anchor" must be bound, like this :

```
$.History.bind(function (state) {...});
```

Where state is my anchor name.